# TypeError: groupby() missing 1 required positional argument: 'operations'

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, recommendation-engine

when i trying to run this command

```
train_data.groupby('item_id')['purchase_count'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20)
```

on my notebook of google colab I incountered this issue:

```
TypeError: groupby() missing 1 required positional argument: 'operations'
```

there is a way to change it in order to obtain the running of command ?

Comment: What does `train_data` look like? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sounds like you are not calling the groupby method on a regular DataFrame - because there is no positional argument called "operations" on the groupby function of a pd.DataFrame. Check the type of train_data first.